# How to talk about the end / finish of the washing machine in the following context?

Tags: sentence-choice

Assuming I turned on the washing machine and I'm waiting until it finished (?). What's the idiomatic choice out of the following ones (if any...) when I'm telling my friend about my plan now:

1. I'll wait until the washing machine will finish.
2. I'll wait until the washing machine will end.
3. I'll be waiting until the washing machine (or simply: it) will be done.
4. I'll be waiting for the machine to be ended / finished / done.

I'm not sure how to phrase what I want to say, sounding natural.

Comment: I would probably say "I'm waiting for the wash cycle to finish."

Comment: @Kate Your suggestion sounds simple and nice. Thanks. So 'to finish' in your example means 'to be finished', right?

Comment: It means 'to come to an end'.

Comment: None of the versions with "will" are correct. In each case, replace the "will"-form with *present simple* to make them at least grammatically correct.

Comment: **Where is the washing machine? Is it in your home or in a laundrette?** And for context, why do you have to wait until the washing has been done? I have gone to bed many a time while the washing machine was running, to then wake up the next morning and hang the damp laundry out.

Comment: My house. Well, the reason is for putting it in the dryer.

Answer (score 4):

When referring to future time in dependent clauses, you typically use the present tense. There's no need for the future progressive in the main clause here. When describing washing machines, "finish" and "do" are, I think, more common than "end." So you would say:

> I'll wait until the washing machine's finished

Or:

> I'll wait until the washing machine's done.

If you're waiting *currently,* you would use "I'm waiting" rather than "I'll wait."

Comment: And in OP's 3/4 the "I'll be waiting" would refer to doing the washing sometime in the future, not now.

Answer (score 2):

None of these are quite correct. =/

Try **I'll wait until the washing machine is finished.**

or

**I'll wait until the washing machine finishes.**

Think of it like this:

[I'll wait...] - the time sense of this clause is "now", the speaker's present.  The action in this clause happens relative to "now", so if we want to describe an event in the future, we must use the future tense.

[until...] - we introduce a new time sense for what comes after "until", that is sometime after "now". Actions in this clause happens relative to the specific moment "sometime after 'now'", so it's OK to use the present tense to refer to this time.

Using this way of thinking, we can see we can also make sense of other uses of tense such as "I'll be waiting until the washing machine has finished."

"I'll be waiting" - ongoing present action, relative to "now"

"the washing machine has finished" - currently completed past action relative to the second time sense, which is "sometime after 'now'".

Answer (score -1):

> I'll wait until the washing machine is done before I put the clothes in the dryer.

Put the emphasis on the completion of the wash cycle.

> I'll be waiting until the washing machine is done because I don't want the clothes to sit wet.

Puts the emphasis on you waiting.  This also implies you will be in close proximity to the washing machine.

Your examples are not technically wrong, but they put the focus on the machine finishing it's cycle which is less relevant than the actual washing being done.

Comment: "This also implies you will be in close proximity to the washing machine."  I don't think this is true at all.  "Ill be waiting for you to write."  Is the speaker in close proximity to the listener?

Comment: Please remain kind and topical.   Do you think the speaker is in close proximity to the listener in my example above?   To wit:  If the speaker of your example were sitting in a lounge chair by the pool, would they be waiting by the pool?

Comment: @BadZen I don't usually read other people's answers but....either of you examples are practically equivalent and the correct for of OP's 1 & 2.  However, OP's 3 & 4 convey a different importance to the speaker, their waiting vs the cycle finishing.

Comment: @BadZen OP does not mention proximity, but if you state you _waiting_ for the washer to finish sipping margaritas by the pool, you're likely to get poked fun at.  "Oh, laundry day is so tough! :)"  Kind and topical?  Ha, stop downvoting me for no reason.

Comment: Downvoting is not unkind, and I explain my reasons in both cases.    I just want you to fix the very bad grammar in this answer so that readers / learners are not confused by seeing it.    (Retributive / serial downvoting, on the other hand, is prohibited / not helpful.)   Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147592/discussion-between-badzen-and-johns-305).

Comment: @BadZen  `"This also implies you will be in close proximity to the washing machine." I don't think this is true at all.` How else would a person know when the machine has finished washing? You have to be in the same house  as the washing machine before you can take out the load. You have to be at home before you tell someone "I can't come until the machine's finished". Obviously no one is obliged to be home or in the same room while their laundry is being done, but the OP's request heavily hints that's where they are.

Comment: @Johns-305 if by saying "Close proximity"  you meant to be in the *vicinity* or in the same building  where the washing machine is, then consider changing the phrase to "near". But if the  washing machine is in a public laundrette, you  wait in front of the machine (i.e. *close proximity*!) until it's finished its cycle. If you don't, someone might run off with your  newly washed laundry!

Comment: @Mari-LouA While it might a be good idea, likely, or logical that the speaker "remain near the washing machine", this is different than the claim that the language itself implies that the speaker will.  Since the comments above, the example was edited to add some more intention ("I don't want the clothes to sit wet"), but this still falls short of that /meaning/. Also, note that the original question doesn't even make it clear that we're talking about a clothes washer. We should avoid unnecessary inferences when explaining language to learners, so that they can avoid unintended meaning later.

Comment: @BadZenn.if something is potentially ambiguous it's a good idea to post a comment, underneath the original post-- in this case the question--asking for clarification.